# C++ return value without return statement

Tags: c++, return-value

When I ran this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int sqr(int&);

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    std::cout<<"Square of (5) is: "<< sqr(a) <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"After pass, (a) is: "<< a <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int sqr(int &x)
{
    x= x*x;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
Square of (5) is: 2280716
After pass, (a) is: 25
```

What is `2280716`? And, how can I get a value returned to `sqr(a)` while there is no `return` statement in the function `int sqr(int &x)`?

Thanks.

Comment: WTF? Why would you want to write such code? Clearly sqr is a mathematical function and it makes no sense to use the parameter as in-out.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan. Just testing how pass by reference works

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Strictly, this causes **undefined behavior**. In practice, since `sqr` has return type `int`, it will always return something, even if no `return` statement is present. That something can be any `int` value.

Add a `return` statement and turn on warnings in your compiler (`g++ -Wall`, for instance).

```
int sqr(int &x)
{
    return x = x*x;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `-Wall`. (Now, if you'd add `-Werror` ... no, I can't upvote twice, damn. :-))

Comment: It is a little less simple, not returning anything in a function with a return type other than `void` causes undefined behavior, not just the return of an undefined value. The difference is that stating that it will return an undefined value means that by simply ignoring that value everything will be fine, but that is not so. The program could crash, corrupt the stack...

Comment: @David just to clarify the undefined behavior bit and make sure I understand the issue entirely; if, for instance, our return value were a unique_ptr<T>, without a return statement, the function would return garbage in place of a T*, which would then be interpreted by the caller as a valid unique_ptr, and even if you were to ignore it, the pretend unique_ptr's destructor would crash your program(hopefully) while trying to delete its pointee.

Answer (score 8):

That's some garbage that will depend on a handful of factors. Likely that's the value stored in memory where the function would put the result if it had a `return` statement. That memory is left untoched and then read by the caller.

Don't think of it too much - just add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `sqr()` has no return statement. The function has undefined behavior concerning return value. Your first output shows this return value.

The compiler should show a diagnostic though.

try this:

```
int sqr(int x)
{
  return x*x;
}
```

Comment: `g++ -Wall` for default warnings. Check out the manual for specific warnings.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print the return value of sqr(int &x), which is garbage value in this case. But not returning the proper X*X.
try returning valid X*X from sqe

> `int sqr(int &x) { x= x*x; return x;}`

Answer (score 2):

If a function is not declared `void` then you **MUST** have a return statement telling what should be the value when returning to the caller. If you fail to do so and simply the function end without returning a value the result of calling this function is ["Undefined Behavior"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that means that your program could do anything (including crashing or deleting everything that is on your hard disk).

Normally if the value is just a simple int you will get funky numbers, but in more complex cases can be a source of big troubles. Just don't do that.

Compilers will normally inform you that you forgot a return statement if properly instructed to do so (i.e. by enabling the maximum warning level). You can omit to return a value only for cases where the function doesn't actually return (i.e. throws an exception or loops forever).

Also, because of a crazy special rule of the C++ language, the function `main` can end without a `return` statement despite being declared as returning an `int`. Don't waste your time your time looking for a logical reason for this exception, there's none.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a choice between:

1) Passing by reference/value AND return an INT.

2) Passing by reference AND return void.

This choice depends on the purpose of your function.

If you want a function that gives you the square of a number use the first.  If you want a function that takes a variable and replaces it by its square, use the second.

So either:

```
int sqr(int& x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

OR

```
void sqr(int& x)
{
    x= x*x;
}
```