# why does this recursion program work?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,x;
    int fact(int);

    cin >> n;

    x = fact(n);

    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

int fact(int n) {
    if(n!=1)
        return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

In the last case, when the argument passed to the function fact is 1, how is it able to calculate that `fact(1)` is equal to 1, without me specifying it in my code?

Comment: This does not work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7260c2ee17d556.  You need a better compiler/warnings.

Comment: When your code reaches the end of function `fact` without `return`, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: i used codeblocks ide to compile the above code, and it is giving me the correct answer , is codeblocks unreliable ?

Comment: @srishti77714 I think that it would benefit you to study up on how to properly define a recursive method. What you have in your code is only half of a recursive solution, at best.

Comment: @srishti77714 Apparently your compiler is not issuing a warning message to you. This may have to do with the level of warnings you have or have not asked for in Code::Blocks' preferences.

Comment: yes , I totally agree with you , I have just started learning recursion, so I saw this code somewhere , even I thought it is wrong but then i was confused when it was giving a correct output .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This program relies on undefined behavior. It is certainly not guaranteed to work, but you may have found a situation in which the parameter you send (1) is in a place where the calling code perceives it as the return value. Do **not** depend on this behavior.

Many C++ compilers would reject this code as having a semantic issue: *Not all control paths return a value from **fact()***

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int fact(int n);
> ```

This function signature returns an integer, but when n=1 is given there is no corresponding return statement in your implementation.  In that case, the function may return any `int` value (i.e. garbage in memory) and the behaviour is **undefined**.  You should not depend on this, even though your compiler allows it to run.

I'm quite certain you saw a warning when compiling your program.  In my environment (g++ on Mac OSX), the compiler issued the following warning:

> warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Personally, I don't think there is any good reason for a compiler to allow this kind of bug (i.e. it should fail to compile).

Reference: A similar question is found below:

[C++ return value without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815819/c-return-value-without-return-statement)

Comment: Hi Toby, I've updated the answer to add full description.  Thanks for the review.

Comment: I have seen a MSVC++ 10 get a little over-zealous. I wrote a non-void function with a `switch` statement, _all_ of whose cases, including `default` returned a value. The compiler complained that I didn't have a `return` statement as the last statement before the function's closing curly brace. There was no way control could ever reach the closing curly brace, but I had to add a bogus `return` statement just to avoid the error message.

Comment: I think it's a bit off-topic but it's interesting point.  In my opinion, MSVC++10's should've allowed your program to be compiled as you specified all the possible cases.  i.e., I don't think there is any good reason for a compiler not to allow a good program ;-)